# How to set limit on directory size in Linux?

Tags: linux, directory, size, limit

I have read about limiting size of directory - like creating big files, formatting, mount,.. etc.
But this is all very complicated. Does a utility or something else exist to set a limit on an already existing directory?

Comment: The problem that I need limit to specific directories. There are many users that have access to e.g. direcotry1, directory2, directory3. I need set limit for log dir, for data dir, for applications dir.

Comment: Why do you ask? What is the context?

Comment: Based on the accepted answer and the linked tutorial, I've put together a script to automate the process, which is actually was made for a related answer: https://askubuntu.com/a/1043139/295286

Answer (score 64, accepted):

> Quota is based upon filesystems, but you can always create a virtual filesystem and mount it on a specific (empty) directory with the usrquota and/or grpquota flags.

In steps this will be:

1. create the mount point
2. create a file full of /dev/zero, large enough to the maximum size you want to reserve for the virtual filesystem
3. format this file with an ext3 filesystem (you can format a disk space even if it is not a block device, but double check the syntax of every - dangerous - formatting command)
4. mount the newly formatted disk space in the directory you've created as mount point, e.g.
   Code:
   `mount -o loop,rw,usrquota,grpquota /path/to/the/formatted/disk/space /path/of/mount/point`
5. Set proper permissions
6. Set quotas
   and the trick is done.

Tutorial [here](http://souptonuts.sourceforge.net/quota_tutorial.html).
Original answer [here](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-server-73/directory-quota-601140/)

Answer (score 5):

You could limit the [quota](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Quota.html) on a filesystem. But it is not directory specific, but file system & user specific.

You might also consider developping your own user space file system using [FUSE](http://fuse.sourceforge.net/), but this will take your time.