# Can a memory limit be placed on a folder

Tags: linux, memory, memory-management

For one of my projects, I need to simulate an out-of-storage error.

On linux, can a storage space limit be set on a folder?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_quota

Comment: A "folder" is an abstraction of the gui.  If you want to set quotas on the filesystem, you will be working with objects called "directories".

Comment: Take a look at the following links:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148715/how-to-set-limit-on-directory-size-in-linux

http://serverfault.com/questions/105040/restrict-directory-size