# Docker - Limit mounted volume size

Tags: docker, docker-volume

Is there any way to limit the size that a mounted docker volume can grow to? I'm thinking of doing it like it's done here: [How to set limit on directory size in Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8148715/how-to-set-limit-on-directory-size-in-linux) but I feel it's a bit too convoluted for what I need.

Answer (score 2):

By default when you mount a host directory/volume into your Docker container while running it, the Docker container gets full access to that directory and can use as much space as is available.

The way you're trying is yeah, tedious.

What you can do is, for, eg. maybe mount a new partition to your server, (maybe an EBS to your EC2 instance) with limited size and mount that inside your container and that will suit your purpose.