# Is there a good way to test partial write failures to files?

Tags: python, unit-testing

Is there a good way to test partial write failures to files?  I'm particularly interested in simulating a full disk.

I have some code which modifies a file.  For some failures there's nothing the code can do, eg: if the disk is unplugged while writing.  But for other predictable failures, such as disk full, my code should (and can) catch the exception and undo all changes since the most recent modification began.

I *think* my code does this well, but am struggling to find a way to exhaustively unit test it.  It's difficult to write a unit test to limit a real file system<sup>1</sup>.  I don't see any way to limit a [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BytesIO).  I'm not aware of any mock packages for this.

Are there any standard tools/techniques for this before I write my own?

---

<sup>1</sup> Limiting a real file system is hard for a few reasons. The biggest difficulty is that file systems are usually limited by blocks of a few KiB not bytes.  It's hard to make this test all unhappy paths.  That is, a good test would be repeated with limits of different lengths to ensuring every individual `file.write(...)` errors in test, but achieving this with block sizes of say 4KiB is going to be difficult.

Comment: What platform? On Linux for example you can create a virtual filesystem with a defined size limit: https://stackoverflow.com/q/8148715/3001761

Comment: @jonrsharpe The code isn't limited to an OS at the moment.  Even if it was, using the OS to limit this would still be problematic as per my edit.

Comment: *"a good test would be repeated with limits of different lengths"* - I don't see why. You're trying to make sure that your code handles the error appropriately, not that the file system handles limits correctly, or that the OS/Python throws the right error. You could write one integration-style test where the write exceeds the available size and validate that the result is a rollback rather than a partial update. More granular testing, if needed, can happen at the unit level with a mock that throws the matching error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I need to undo more than a single `file.write()`.  The code to rollback must perform different tasks depending on which write fails so as I stated, I need to test all unhappy **paths**, not just one.  The important thing here is that different lengths (sometimes of a few bytes) will caused different `file.write()` to fail and thus different cleanup.

Answer (score 4):

*Disclaimer*: I'm a contributor to pyfakefs.

This may be overkill for you, but you could simulate the whole file system using [pyfakefs](https://github.com/jmcgeheeiv/pyfakefs). This allows you to set the file system size beforehand. Here is a trivial example using pytest:

```py
def test_disk_full(fs):  # fs is the file system fixture
    fs.set_disk_usage(100)  # sets the file system size in bytes
    os.makedirs('/foo')
    with open('/foo/bar.txt', 'w') as f:
        with pytest.raises(OSError):
            f.write('a' * 200)
            f.flush()
```